# How can Pass string as parameter in Web Api C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-ajax, windows-forms-designer

How can I pass string parameter in Web API

> {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   'http://localhost:60698/api/values/GetBynamed/sudeesh3'.","MessageDetail":"No
>   action was found on the controller 'Values' that matches the
>   request."}

```
public IHttpActionResult getbynamed(string name)
    {
                List<ImgModel> list1 = new List<ImgModel>();
                ImgModel mod = new ImgModel();
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed) con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_details where name='" + name + "'", con);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows)
                { 
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {

                        mod.id = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString());
                        mod.img = dr[1].ToString();
                        mod.name = dr[2].ToString();
                        mod.phone = dr[3].ToString();
                        list1.Add(mod);
                    }
                    return Ok(list1);
                }
                else
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this one:

```
[Route("api/values/getbynamed/{name}"]
public IHttpActionResult getbynamed(string name)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need add route configure for API

```
[Route("api/values/getbynamed/{name}")]
public IHttpActionResult getbynamed(string name)
{
}
```